# Returning caught error observable from catchError in HttpInterceptor causes error loop

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have a simple interceptor that handles requests and catches any http error using RXJS catchError. The second argument received in catchError is the caught observable. I want to, in some cases, return this error and let it propagate up to the error handler in the subscribe function. The problem is that returning th caught error causes an infinite loop (as seen in the example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u4gakr)

The intercept function in the interceptor where the catchError is stuck in a loop when reciving an HTTP error, like 404:

```
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error, caught$) => {
      console.log('Returning caught observable'); 
      return caught$;
    })
  );
```

I have probably misunderstood something about the interceptor or RxJS catchError. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out I needed to use `return throwError(error)` as returning the caught observable, or of(error) both failed to return it properly to the subscribe functions error handler.

The final code is then:

```js
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error) => {
      console.log('Returning caught observable'); 
      return throwError(() => new Error('The Error'));
    })
  );
```

Answer (score 4):

`caught$` is your original observable. When I describe in English what you have programmed, then it is something like "do something and when it fails, then log it and do it again".

It is worth it to have a look into the documentation of rxjs, there is this behavior described.

> a function that takes as arguments err, which is the error, and caught, which is the source observable, in case you'd like to "retry" that observable by returning it again.

Source: https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/catchError

So, it is up to you to decide what you want to do.
You can retry the call (perhaps with a delay) in case of a `503` (service is not available). Or you can build an error-object and return this instead.

```
return next.handle(request)
  .pipe(
    catchError((error, caught$) => {
      // a retry-logic
      if (error.status === 503) {
         return timer(5_000).pipe(switchMap(() -> caught$));
      }
     
      // non-error-return
      console.log(...);
      return of({ result: { error: error; });
    })
  );

// other option: send a message to user
return next.handle(request)
   .pipe(
      catchError((error) => {
         this.messageBoxService.showErrorMessage('there was a problem, while talking the server');
         return throwError(error);
      })
   );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the return to just be this and the subscribe will handle the error.

```
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<any> {
    const requestCopy = request.clone();
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
      if (error.status === 404) {
        return throwError(error)
      } else {
        return of()
      }
    }))
  }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zz3glp

Comment: It solves the loop, but i never recive the error in the error handler for the subscribe function

Comment: Oh you can just remove the pipe and all that then from the handler

Comment: Unfortunately not, as I need to handle some error codes, like 401, and pass others on, like with 404

Comment: You could just handle it in the subscribe, but otherwise you could use Jan's method above and throw some cases in there (updated my answer). Note I switched the method return type.