# Angular/RxJx - Accessing response headers on failed request

Tags: angular, error-handling, header, request, rxjs

Let's say that I make a GET-request and subscribe to the resulting stream.
In the case the request fails I want to access the headers of the response to pass them on to my error reporting tool.

The error passed to `handleError` contains its own headers-object but that will always be empty even though I can read the response headers fine in my browser.

My understanding is that the stream throws an error object which is distinct from the failed stream.

```
http.get('url').pipe(
  catchError((err: HttpErrorResponse) => handleError(err))
).subscribe(...);
```

Now, I know that `catchError()` supplies a second argument, named **caught**, which is the original (failed) stream, but I can't pass that on or subscribe to it because I risk creating an [infinite loop of failing requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51948677/returning-caught-error-observable-from-catcherror-in-httpinterceptor-causes-erro).

What am I missing?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. You said you cant subscribe to it for reasons given. So what do you want to do? Do you want to have some retry logic and then give up?

Comment: So `error.headers.get("Header-Name")` does not work?

Comment: @danday74 I need to read from one of the headers so that the error handler can dispatch an event to the error handling library that I'm using.
@David `error.headers.get("Header-Name")` will be null since the whole headers-object of the error is always empty even though the response itself has headers.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out the the HttpErrorResponse headers are empty because I had not properly set the **Access-Control-Expose-Headers**-header in the response returned by my endpoint.

Setting it to include the key for the property I wanted to access made this header available through the HttpErrorResponse.headers!